# How to convert DateTime value C# into something like 31st January 2009 but in Polish Language?

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-3.0

How to convert DateTime.Now (or basically any other DateTime format) to something like 31st January 2009 (although i would like it in polish so i need 29 Styczeń 2009). Do i need to create some array and check each month number with that array or there's some built in feature to save the day?

With regards,

MadBoy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CultureInfo polish = new CultureInfo("pl-PL");  // I *think* this is Polish -- you might need to check!
DateTime.Now.ToString("d MMMM yyyy", polish);
```

The CultureInfo already knows about month names in different locales -- if you need this info explicitly, e.g. to print out a list of month names, you can get it from the DateTimeFormatInfo class, but for a simple formatting requirement it's easier just to use DateTime.ToString with the required culture and a format string.

Comment: That partially works. But can i make it show whole month? Right now it only shows 3 letters? I used varDo.ToString("d MMMMMMMMMMMMMM yyyy", polish) and it seems to work but is it the proper way?

Comment: Use 4 Ms.  Produces "stycznia" which seem more correct then "Styczeń".

Answer (score 0):

I'd format it using a [DateTimeFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) with a Culture or Locale variable.  The Date abstraction is independent of the way you render it.